# Access SQL/Power Query - Matching Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, powerbi, powerpivot, powerquery

I would like to know how can I match these 2 tables - Table 1 and Table 2 - in order to get Table 3 as the final result. The "*" represents any string.

See Tables:

[image]

I could do this comparing each row from Table 1 to all rows from Table 2 which resulted in an intermediate table with 15 rows (5*3). The problem is if both tables have a huge number of rows. I'm trying to do this using Power Query and Access and couldn't find a good solution to avoid this yet. Could you help me? Thanks!

Note 1: Here is a solution using Power Query - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6zc-kQ8qyc4dGhTeTdlVTdYTG8

Comment: could you please add the code you have already tried, and the resources you checked for your problem

Comment: Need rules. Why is Anna Smith the exception? Why would some names have the same Sales data? That is really representative example of data in Table2? If so, why is there an Age field? There is really an * as data in Surname and Age?

Comment: I tried to simplify a more complex problem creating these small tables - this is not a real problem. Please check the Note 1 I added to the original thread with a solution using Power Query.

Comment: By the way, in relation to 'Anna' in Table 2: if 2 rows have the same Name, the one that has more details should be positioned before in order to remove the other one (removing duplicates) when creating Table 3.